# scope on routes with mercury editor + rails 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mercury-editor

I'm checking mercury editor https://github.com/jejacks0n/mercury on small project.

These is my routes.rb file

```
Myapp::Application.routes.draw do
  mount Mercury::Engine => '/'
  scope '(:locale)' do
    resources :post
  end
end
```

My post url are:

```
http://localhost:3000/es/posts/1
http://localhost:3000/en/posts/2
http://localhost:3000/de/posts/3
.
.
.
```

My mercury routes:

```
Routes for Mercury::Engine:
mercury_editor  /editor(/*requested_uri)(.:format)        mercury#edit
                /mercury/:type/:resource(.:format)        mercury#resource
                /mercury/snippets/:name/options(.:format) mercury#snippet_options
                /mercury/snippets/:name/preview(.:format) mercury#snippet_preview
```

I'm try something like:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', "/editor" + request.path %>
```

but I get a wrong url `http://localhost:3000/editor/es/posts/2`.

**can someone say me how add a specify path to my routes for something like:**

`http://localhost:3000/es/editor/posts/1` or `http://localhost:3000/editor/posts/1`

Comment: What do you mean by "I get a wrong url" ? Does this url work but you don't like how it looks ? Or does the url not work at all ?

For what it's worth I've just been in the same case you've been and ended up doing just what you did. And it's all working fine with that url `http://localhost:3000/editor/es/posts/2`

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<%= link_to 'Edit', "/editor" + request.path %>` with

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', request.path.gsub(/^\/((\w)+)/, '/\1/editor') %>
```

to get `http://localhost:3000/es/editor/posts/1`

Or

Replace `<%= link_to 'Edit', "/editor" + request.path %>` with

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', request.path.gsub(/^\/((\w)+)/, '/editor') %>
```

to get `http://localhost:3000/editor/posts/1`

even you can define a helper method like

```
def mercuryfied_url(with_locale = true)
  if with_locale 
    request.path.gsub(/^\/((\w)+)/, '/\1/editor')
  else
    request.path.gsub(/^\/((\w)+)/, '/editor')
  end
end
```

then call

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', mercuryfied_url %>
```

to get `http://localhost:3000/es/editor/posts/1`

Or

```
   <%= link_to 'Edit', mercuryfied_url(false) %>
```

to get `http://localhost:3000/editor/posts/1`

Hope that helps :)